# Getting error in sql query

Tags: php, posts, sql

I am saving a post id in a variable with the_id() function. And then i need to fetch the data of same post id from database . As post id is working fine but i am getting error while executing get result . below is the code . Can anyone please help ?

```
             $a = the_ID();; 
           global $wpdb;
            $data = $wpdb->get_results("SELECT `id`,`guid` FROM `wp_posts` WHERE `post_type` = 'local-offer' group by `post_author`");


            $result = $wpdb->get_results("SELECT * FROM `wp_postmeta` WHERE `post_id` = ".$a." ");
```

Comment: What is the error? Are you getting incorrect results? Empty results? Error values? PHP Warnings? PHP Errors? Note that you haven't called `prepare` so `$a` could be used in an SQL injection attack, have you considered just calling `get_post_meta( $a )`? Or using `WP_Query`? I see no reason whatsoever for you to be using raw SQL at all here, not to mention you're bypassing the object cache/pre-fetching so this may actually be a lot slower than using the APIs

Answer (score 0):

You have a typo

```
$a = the_ID(); 
$data = $wpdb->get_results("SELECT `id`,`guid` FROM `wp_posts` WHERE `post_type` = 'local-offer' group by `post_author`");
$result = $wpdb->get_results("SELECT * FROM `wp_postmeta` WHERE `post_id` = ".$a." ");
```

Answer (score 0):

Your entire approach here is wrong, so lets break it apart line by line:

```
$a = the_ID();
```

`the_ID` echo's the post ID, this is not the correct function to use, instead use `get_the_ID()`. Notice that in WP functions beginning with `the_` output data, and functions beginning with `get_` return data.

```
$data = $wpdb->get_results("SELECT `id`,`guid` FROM `wp_posts` WHERE `post_type` = 'local-offer' group by `post_author`");
```

Here you're fetching post IDs from the post table where the post type is `local-offer`, grouped by post author, but this SQL query is unnecessary and slower! You're bypassing `WP_Cache` so it has to retrieve everything from scratch, and there's already an API for doing this, `WP_Query`:

```
$q = new WP_Query( [
    'post_type' => 'local-offer',
    'orderby' => 'author'
    'order' => 'ASC',
    'fields' => 'ids'
] );
$data = $q->posts;
```

Here we use `WP_Query` to fetch the posts, telling it to only fetch ID's, order by author, and only the `local-offer` post type, refer to the docs for more options, as well as using it to create a post loop for displaying things.

```
$result = $wpdb->get_results("SELECT * FROM `wp_postmeta` WHERE `post_id` = ".$a." ");
```

Here we have an SQL query to fetch all key value pairs for a given post ID, however:

- there's no validation here, leaving you wide open to SQL injection attacks
- there's already an easy API call for this!

You can replace this with:

```
$result = get_post_meta( $a );
```